# node-mysql multiple instances is failing

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

For example, in a socket.io connection event ***handleServer* is the callback function**:

```
function handleServer(s)
{
    m = new mysql();
    m.Query("blabla",function(r)
    {
        console.log(r)
    });
    m.Close();
}
```

mysql object is:

```
m = require("mysql");

function Mysql()
{
    this.mysql = m.createConnection({ blablah });
    this.mysql.connect(function(err)
    {
        // blabla
    });
}

Mysql.prototype.Query = function(q, callback)
{
    this.mysql.query(q, function(err, v)
    {
        callback(v);
    })
}
```

In the first function call (handleServer) the query is correctly executed, but in the successive calls this fails throwing

> "m has no method 'createConnection' "

Theoretically should not create another connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you dont need to create a new instance everytime.

The problem with your code is that you are using the same global var `m` for two different objects.

Inside your mysql func definition you are defining the global var `m` as the mysql module and then you are redifining the global `m` as `new mysql`.

Try this:

```
var m = new mysql();
```

Comment: Oh, but the first code is in mysql.js script and the second code is in sio.js script. can the global variable m in a script affect another script?

Comment: oh, yes, it's true. the includes are inherited